# codemirror string coloring multiple lines

Tags: codemirror

I'm using codemirror for javascript code coloring, and when I put a string in quotes "like this" it is colored just fine.

But when I put a string with a line break "like

this" the color is messed up on the second line.

Is there any way to make sure the color starts with the first quote and ends with the second quote, even if there is a line break?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't allow multi-line strings. You can use a backslash before the newline, or use template literals (backtick-quoted strings), but if you don't, you aren't writing valid JavaScript, and that is the reason why the CodeMirror mode doesn't highlight your code as you expected.

Comment: I incorrectly stated about the javascript...I'm using the codemirror javascript functionality with a proprietary language that is not supported by codemirror directly.  Javascript looked to be the closest I could come, then make some modifications for the proprietary language.  Multi-line strings are one of those things unfortunately.  Everything else I've needed to modify I've been able to figure out so far, this one is stumping me though...

Comment: Modifying the JavaScript mode for another language is probably not a good idea. Maybe try to write a [simple mode](http://codemirror.net/demo/simplemode.html), which gives you a much cleaner interface. Do you understand the way tokens are limited to a line and you have to keep state to parse multi-line elements? See [my blog](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/codemirror-mode-system.html) for background.